debezium postgres connector able to see by GET but not able to by POST method
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins'
I am able to see the postgres connector installed along with the inbuilt connectors
[{"class":"io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector","type":"source","version":"2.6.1.Final"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector","type":"source","version":"3.7.0"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector","type":"source","version":"3.7.0"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"3.7.0"}]
But when I try POST method it says Failed to find the postgres connector
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 127.0.0.1:8083/connectors/ --data "@debezium.json"
`
{
  "name": "reporting_connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "database.hostname": "xx.xx.xx.xx",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "five",
    "database.password": "five",
    "database.dbname": "reportdb",
    "database.server.name": "report",
    "topic.prefix": "reportdb",
    "table.include.list": "public.table1"
  }
}`

I have installed a standalone kafka latest (not confluent) on a Ubuntu machine and running openJDK 11 version.

"But when I try POST method it says Failed to find the postgres connector"
Can you post the output log when call connector's api ?
